# How to get multiple selected items from QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using QListView and QFileSystemModel to implement file open dialog due to specific requirement. I don't know how get items which I selected using mouse drag (Multiple Selection) when using QListView::ExtendedSelection. I search Qt doc as well but not found any thing useful.
My requirements are ...

- How to know there is multiple selection (signal)
- How to get selected item list

Comment: 1) your_lv->selectionModel()->selectionChanged https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged

Comment: 2) your_lv->selectedIndexes(); https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectedIndexes